# Range Vent Hood Ducting - Can two 5" ducts work in place of one 10" for a range vent hood?

Tags: vent, ducts, range, hood

Purchased a Kitchenaid Range Hood Vent that has a 1200 CFM blower.  Instructions say to install a 10" duct vent.  My existing venting duct was a rigid but small 6 inch duct.

Unfortunately at demo realized that sewer line and other utilities are right in the middle of the ceiling cavity perpendicular to the exit point, 10 feet away = cannot move (cost prohibitive).

A.   Can I used TWO 5" rigid ducts instead of the 10" one required?  How?  I'd think the biggest challenge will be the multiple reducers needed to go from 10-8, 8-6, for both lines.  And a Y-joint somewhere...

B.   What if I used the existing 6" duct and merely added a 4 inch line?  Or two-6 inch ducts?

(I will also be adding some mineral wool insulation for sound absorption right above the range but the goal is not to have to tear down the ceiling either.)

Comment: Cross sectional area of a 5" duct = 78.54 square inches.  Cross sectional area of a 10" duct = 314.16 square inches... 6" duct = 113.1 square inches, 4" = 50.27 square inches...

Comment: That is a lot of CFM, is your cooktop huge or kitchen massive? You may not need that much CFM

Comment: In other words, 2x 5" ducts gives you a 157.08 square inch duct (cross section), which is a lot less than the 314.16 square inches you get from one 10" duct. So if you actually REQUIRE the equivalent of a 10" round duct, this won't do it. You'd need almost 4x 5" ducts to do the job. If you were talking rectangular ducts, it would be a different story.

Comment: @Comintern's values are incorrect but the ratio between duct sizes is. Formula for area of a circle is pi * radius squared, not diameter squared. So 5" is about 20 sq in and 10" duct is about 78 sq in.

Comment: @topshot - You're right of course, I guess I should check what the inputs of online calculators are...

Comment: Kitchenaid blowers for the range were only 600 or 1200 cfm.  This is a professional 36" range.  What size rectangular duct would be sufficient?  Would any of this change if I reduced for the 600 CFM blower?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the numbers and you can see what your options are.

The numbers are as follows:

On the **left: CFM (Cubic Feet per Minute, cfm)**

On the **right: Equivalent Diameter Round Duct Size**s

200 : 4.9

300 : 5.7

400 : 6.6

750 : 8.3

1000 : 9.1

1250 : 9.8

1500 : 10.7

1750 : 11.5